# Arrows not pointing properly in align environment

Tags: align

I’m trying to achieve the arrangement in this picture with the align environment.

[image]

Here’s my code.

```
\begin{align*}
&0 \ < &1 \ < &\dots \ < &m \ < &m+1 \ < &\dots \ < (n-1)^2\\
&\uparrow
\end{align*}
```

which gives me

> [image]

The spacing looks weird, plus the arrow does not point directly at the entry 0. Would appreciate if anyone could help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With `array` is easy:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
    \begin{array}{*{12}{c}}
0        & < & 1       & < & \dotsm & < & m       & < & m+1     & < & \dotsm < & (n-1)^2  \\
\uparrow &   &\uparrow &   &        &   &\uparrow &   &\uparrow &   &          &\uparrow  \\
\phi     & < & A       & < & \dotsm & < & F'      & < & F       & < & \dotsm < & ASM_n    \\
\end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with `array`, but with some tweaking to use the standard math spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% let TeX add the right spacing
\begin{array}{
  c             % centered symbol
  *{6}{         % repeat six times
    >{{}}c<{{}} % centered relation symbol
    c           % centered symbol
  }
}
0         &<& 1        &<& \cdots &<& m        &<& m+1      &<& \cdots   &<& (n-1)^2 \\
\uparrow  & & \uparrow & &        & & \uparrow & & \uparrow & &          & & \uparrow \\
\emptyset &<& A        &<& \cdots &<& F'       &<& F        &<& \cdots   &<& \mathit{ASM}_n
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note the `\mathit` around `ASM`, because I believe this is a single object, not the product of A by S by M.

[image]